# Dynamically add Binds to a GIN Module

Tags: java, gwt, guice, gwt-gin, gwt-platform

Can I add binds to a GIN module dynamically?

For example, having a module "ExampleModule," and calling a static method on it, eg:

```
bind (Test.class, TestImpl.class);
```

and GIN do the bind automatically?

Or maybe using annotations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you're after, but you can annotate the `Test` class with `@ImplementedBy(TestImpl.class)` to save you the `bind(Test.class).to(TestImpl.class)` in your `GinModule`.
See http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/JustInTimeBindings

Comment: One thing to mention: GIN works at compile-time; it uses your `GinModule` as a Guice module and then uses Guice's inspection capabilities (Elements API) to get the bindings back and generate the appropriate client-side code, depending on types accessible from the `Ginjector` and their dependencies. So everything has to be reachable *from* the `GinModule` (and not otherwise); calling a static `bind()` from elsewhere is not possible.

Comment: hmm, thats true. Thanks for help.